# How to only display ads in one version of your app

Tags: android, xml, admob, ads, android-productflavors

I am planning on an ads vs. ad-free version of my app. I already have two app flavors set up.

In my XML, this [AdMob tutorial](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/06/how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-android.html) says I add this to my activity XML to hold the banner ad:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/admob_adview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_footer" />
```

And then in the code, the tutorial says:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdMobAdView;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdMobAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.admob_adview);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("4DD0986B8BB49093161F4F00CF61B887")// Add your real device id here
                .build();
        mAdMobAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But if I only want this ad to display on one flavor vs. the other, what's the correct way to handle this without violating any rules? Normally flavors are checked via something like

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("adfree")) {
    //no ads
}
else {
    //show ads
}
```

Would I simply put the `adRequest` code in the above if-statement within my Activity? For the ad-free version, does it matter that the `AdView` is still in my XML, or do I need to use a separate copy of the XML with the `AdView` removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is not specific to AdMob, and so there may be options or limitations tied to AdMob that render this analysis moot.

However, IMHO, in the ad-free app, you want AdMob totally gone. Why would you bother having it in there, taking up space, possibly crashing with uninitialized views, etc.? It just seems like an unnecessary cost to you and your users.

To do that (referring to your two flavors `ad` and `addfree`):

Step #1: For AdMob-specific dependencies, use `adCompile` instead of `compile`

Step #2: Have the layout resource(s) with the AdMob `AdView` in `ad/src/res/layout/`, with equivalents with the same names in `adfree/src/res/layout` (so you can redesign around having no ad taking up space)

Step #3: Define an `AdStrategy` strategy class in both the `ad/` and `adfree/` source sets, with the same public API, where the `ad/` one has method(s) tied to AdMob (such as that initialization code) and the `adfree/` one just has empty methods

Step #4: In `MainActivity` and anywhere else you interact with AdMob from Java, call the appropriate `AdStrategy` method, so in `ad` builds you get the AdMob stuff and in `adfree` builds it does nothing (or alternative logic, if appropriate)

Now your `adfree` builds are truly AdMob-free, not just AdMob-uninitialized.

Comment: What is `adCompile`? I don't see this on Google

Comment: @KaliMa: You can prefix `compile` with any build type, product flavor, or build variant to restrict the scope of the compilation to that target. So, for a product flavor named `ad`, `adCompile` limits that dependency to the `ad` product flavor, and it will be skipped on other product flavors. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#dependencies).

Comment: When you say `adfree/src/res/layout` I only seem to have `app/src/` (i.e. there is only one main `src` folder). Do I have to add the folders manually? Any other files? Is there a name for this in documentation where I can see an example?

Comment: "Do I have to add the folders manually?" -- well, um, yes. "Any other files?" -- whatever you need. That is up to you. There is nothing that *has* to go in a product flavor's source set, as evidenced by the fact that you don't need to have a source set for a product flavor at all. "Is there a name for this in documentation where I can see an example?" -- "product flavors" and "source sets" are covered in [the documentation on build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html).

Comment: "Do I have to add the folders manually?" -- I asked that in case one had to put something into the Gradle somewhere where it autogenerates the necessary folder/file hierarchies based on the possible flavors, wasn't trying to be dense

Comment: @KaliMa: I can't think of anything in Gradle that generates a directory structure in `src/` (though it certainly does in `build/`, and perhaps I'm forgetting some Gradle tasks that I don't regularly use). And I think that some Android Studio wizards and dialogs will have a drop-down to let you choose a build variant and it will create files in that source set for you. I just create them manually, because that's how I roll. :-)

Comment: To any future readers: See followup answer (also by CommonsWare) about setting up the different flavor-dependent folder hierarchies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44687031/product-flavors-and-source-hierarchies

Answer (score 0):

For me the simplest and most effective way to achieve this would be:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("adfree")) {
mAdMobAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);}

else {mAdMobAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
```

This will make the adView completely go in the ad-free version.