# Product flavors and source hierarchies

Tags: java, android, layout, resources, android-productflavors

My app has two flavors, call it `flavora` and `flavorb` for simplicity.

```
    productFlavors {
        flavora {
            resValue "string", 'app_name', "App Name Flavor A"
            applicationIdSuffix ".flavora"
        }
        flavorb {
            resValue "string", 'app_name', "App Name Flavor B"
            applicationIdSuffix ".flavorb"
        }
    }
```

I want both flavors to use all the same layouts, all the same java code, all the same resources, etc, EXCEPT I want `flavora` and `flavorb` to use different implementations for layout file `flavor_dependent_layout.xml` and Java class `FlavorDependentJavaClass`.

Is this the correct way to do it:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    }
    flavora {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/flavora/res', 'src/main/res']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/flavora/java', 'src/main/java']
    }
    flavorb {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/flavorb/res', 'src/main/res']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/flavorb/java', 'src/main/java']
    }
}
```

And then I'd just create the necessary folders to place the corresponding files, and it'll all work from there naturally? How does it know that I've included the class for both flavors in case I try to perform a method and it only exists for one flavor, for example?

(Also, do I have to explicitly mention assets folders? Since I have `/src/main/assets' as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to do it:

No.

Just create `src/flavora/res/`, `src/flavora/java/`, `src/flavorb/res/`, and `src/flavorb/java/`, and put stuff in there. They will *automatically* be added to the appropriate build paths. You do not need to adjust `srcDirs`.

> How does it know that I've included the class for both flavors in case I try to perform a method and it only exists for one flavor, for example?

That's a build error. With Java code, if you want to have it in flavors:

- The same class cannot exist in `main`
- Anything referenced from `main` has to exist in both `flavora` and `flavorb`

So, for example, if you have an `AdStrategy` class somewhere inside `src/flavora/java/` and somewhere inside `src/flavorb/java/`, you would not *also* have `AdStrategy` in `src/main/java/`. And anything that `main` refers to on `AdStrategy` (constructors, methods, etc.) has to exist in both `flavora` and `flavorb`'s implementation of `AdStrategy`. At build time, when you are building `flavora`, the `src/main/java/` and `src/flavora/java/` trees are used automatically, and whatever you refer to in `main` needs to resolve (likewise for `flavorb` builds).